# From string to hex MD5 hash and back

Tags: java, hash, md5, hex

I have this pseudo-code in java:

```
bytes[] hash = MD5.hash("example");

String hexString = toHexString(hash); //This returns something like a0394dbe93f

bytes[] hexBytes = hexString.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Now, `hexBytes[]` and `hash[]` are different.

I know I'm doing something wrong since `hash.length()` is 16 and `hexBytes.length()` is 32. Maybe it has something to do with java using Unicode for chars (just a wild guess here).

Anyways, the question would be: how to get the original `hash[]` array from the `hexString`.

The whole code is here if you want to look at it (it's ~ 40 LOC) http://gist.github.com/434466

The output of that code is:

```
16
[-24, 32, -69, 74, -70, 90, -41, 76, 90, 111, -15, -84, -95, 102, 65, -10]
32
[101, 56, 50, 48, 98, 98, 52, 97, 98, 97, 53, 97, 100, 55, 52, 99, 53, 97, 54, 102, 102, 49, 97, 99, 97, 49, 54, 54, 52, 49, 102, 54]
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just getting the bytes of the hex string with `hexString.getBytes("UTF-8");` , not converting the hex digits to their byte values.

That is, you need to write the reverse of your `toHexString` function.
Your toHexString should probably make sure to format values below 10 to 2 digits, so e.g. the byte 9 ends up as "09" and not "9".

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown `toHexString`, but basically you need the reverse equivalent - look for a method called `fromHexString` or something similar.

Basically `String.getBytes()` performs a normal encoding (in this case in UTF-8). You want to effectively *decode* the text - which is a textual representation of arbitrary binary data - into a `byte[]`.

[Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) has appropriate methods - the API isn't ideal, but it would work:

```
byte[] data = ...;
String hex = Hex.encodeHexString(data);
...

byte[] decoded = (byte[]) Hex.decode(hex);
```

Comment: the code is in the gist I linked http://gist.github.com/434466 (names vary though). Thanks, I'll look into Apache Commons

Comment: Just curious... why do you say that the API isn't ideal?

Comment: @Pablo: Ideally there should be a Hex.decode method taking a 
String and returning a byte array, strongly typed. The `Object decode(Object)` signature is annoying.

Comment: Oh, I just downloaded the last version and takes a char array and returns a byte array.

Comment: @Pablo: There's an overload that does that, yes - but it's annoying to have to convert to a char array just for this.

Answer (score 1):

getBytes() doesn't parse hexadecimal characters, it processes character encodings. In other words, it doesn't turn '0A' into 0x0A, but into 0x30 0x41, because that's how the characters '0' and 'A' are encoded. You want `Integer.parseInt(String, radix)` instead in your function, with radix==16.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want use a library, here is how you can do it with my version of the hex decoder,

```
byte[] hexBytes = dehexify(hexString);

public static byte[] dehexify(String hexString) {
    if (hexString.length()%2 == 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid length");       
    int len = hexString.length()/2;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        int index = i*2;
        bytes[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(hexString.substring(index, index+2), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```